# Pandas groupby.pct_change() returning 0 and nan only

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset :

```
month      country       user
2018-01    DE            182503
2018-02    DE            168962
2018-03    DE            175043
2019-01    DE            158797
2019-01    DE            226209
```

and I want to see the % change from in consecutive row and I am using `pct_change()` for that but still, my output only contains either nan or 0 or -0.
I want to create a new column, "pct_change" and store percentage change into it.

My user column is of float type.

As of now, my output looks like this

```
month      country       user    pct_change
2018-01    DE            182503  nan
2018-02    DE            168962  -0
2018-03    DE            175043   0
```

I am using the following code:

```
df['pct_change'] = df.groupby(['country'])['user'].pct_change()
```

Why I am not seeing the right results?

Comment: Your code does not match your output

Comment: @user3483203: I have used the exact same code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it just a rounding issue?

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.4f}'.format 
df['pct_change'] = df.groupby(['country'])['user'].pct_change()

df
Out[101]: 
     month country    user  pct_change
0  2018-01      DE  182503         NaN
1  2018-02      DE  168962     -0.0742
2  2018-03      DE  175043      0.0360
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I am so stupid that I had a code line mentioning this : pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.0f' % x). I was just lost I guess, but thanks again!

Comment: Glad to be of help.

Comment: I Will accept the answer in 5 minutes as it is not allowing me to do so before that

Comment: Nice find! @sophods